# Doubt regarding proof that Closure of a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis

I was proving that closure of a set is closed, but I am very confused. Can you please see this proof and check it, please?

Proof: We will prove that every limit point of $\overline{X}$ is a limit point of $X$ as well.

Let $z$ be any limit point of $\overline{X}$. Thus $\forall$ open $U ~ : z\in U ~\exists ~x  \in \overline{X}$  such that $|x-z|<\epsilon$ or $x \in U \cap (\overline{X} / \{z \})$. But then $x \in X/\{z\}$ as well and we are done.

This is kind of more an intuitive, any suggestions would be great :)

Comment: I don't think you have shown $x\in X$

Comment: Can you please help

Comment: There is an $x\in U$ in either $X$ or its boundary. If $x$ is in the boundary of $X$ then, since $U$ is also a neighbourhood of $x$, it contains a point $y\in X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempt:

Let $X$ be a metric space, $A \subset X$, and

$z$ be a limit point of  $\overline {A}$.

Need to show that $z$ is a limit point of $A$.

In every neighbourhood of $z$ there is a point $x$ of $\overline {A}$ \ {$z$}.

Let $x \in B_r(z)$, where $B_r(z): = \{x: d(x, z)<r \}$ is such a neighbourhood.

Since $x \in \overline {A}$ there is in every  neighbourhood of $x$ a point  $a$ of $A$ \ {$x$}, i.e. $a \in B_{\epsilon}(x)$.

Set $d:=d(z,x)(<r)$, and choose $\epsilon= r-d$,

then

$d(z,a) \le d(z,x)+d(x,a)< d +\epsilon$

$=d+r-d=r$, i.e. $a \in B_r(z)$.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Shamim  Thanks. Frankly, I was fiddling myself a bit. Empy 2 in his comment saw the problem in your proof. If anymore questions I'll try to answer. :) Greetings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will always post doubts in MSE here. I am self studying real analysis as i got a lot of time nowadays, thats why i have some doubts :)

Comment: Great idea. A few suggestions, if you do not mind. Write clearly the assumptions. At first I thought you may be dealing with topol. spaces. Then go step by step, checking every step, and at times a drawing can help. Have fun!

Comment: Yup! :) i started with analysis I from Terence Tao's book and i am in section 9 currently and i tried to get a hint from other answers but their terminologies are different. And yes, i always visualise the situation of convergence and limit points, etc. :)

Comment: Keep it up, and have fun. Greetings.